# Reasoning behind expectation of taking two marbles from a bag

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have 5 marbles numbered from 1 through 5 in a bag. Suppose I take out two different balls at random.

a) What is the expected value of the sum of the numbers on the balls?

b) What is the expected value of the product of the numbers on the balls?

I have some problem with this exercise because I don't understand why the expectations of the two random variables , one representing the first extraction and one the second,  are just the same (even though I could manage to calculate it with lots of calculations using condition expectation for the second extraction , but it becomes not a good way with more extractions I think because it requires a lot more calculations). So, applying linearity of expectation for the sum, knowing this, I have: $$E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y] = 2 *E[X]$$ For what regards the second question, I don't know if I can apply the formula for the product of indipendent events to get :$$E[XY] =E[X]E[Y]  = E[X]^2$$  But are they even independent?

Besides , how can I prove the generalization of this formulas for the case with n marbles and m extractions?

Comment: There are only $\binom 52= 10$ cases.  Just do it by hand.

Comment: No, they are not independent. If you take out ball $4$, you can not get ball $4$ again. You should try doing this by hand, there are only $10$ unique cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you are one of the marbles in the bag and your number is e.g. $2$.

Two marbles will be selected. One of them will be labeled as $X$ and the other will be labeled as $Y$.

Now what is your chance to be labeled as $X$?

$\frac15$ of course because there are $5$ equiprobable candidates for that and you are one of them.

Similarly your chance to be labeled as $Y$ is also $\frac15$. In short:$$P(X=2)=\frac15=P(Y=2)$$

This also if you have a different number so evidently $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

$X$ and $Y$ are not independent. For that realize that they cannot both take number $4$ which means that: $$P(X=4\mid Y=4)=0$$By independence we would expect that $P(X=4\mid Y=4)=P(X=4)=\frac15$.

So it is *not correct* to state that $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb EX\times\mathbb EY=(\mathbb EX)^2$.

Comment: But the fact that one is extracted earlier doesn't change the probability of the second to 1/4?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your reasoning...I  just have some problem not to consider the fact that I have to extract one marble first ( I know that the extraction can be simultaneous and it doesn't change nothing one of the other way to think about it )..

Comment: Why is this irrelevant?

Comment: Do you agree that all $5$ marbles have equal chance to become the marble that is drawn as second? That is the essence.

Comment: Yes I agree...but what about the fact that there is one element less for the second one?

Comment: In fact following your explanation since all the marble are equiprobable to become the second all the numbers are equiprobable to come out...Am I right?

Comment: Yes. It assures that $P(Y=i)$ does not depend on $i$. Then consequently $P(Y=i)=1/5$ for  $i=1,2,3,4,5$. Try to grasp this. Things would be different if you must find the distribution of $Y$ under e.g. the *condition* that $X=3$. Then indeed we must take into account that marble 3 is missing. We are not in that situation but must find the *unconditional* probability distribution of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for having helped me!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks about generalising the result to $n$ marbles and $m$ extractions.

**Problem (a)**

Here the expectation method works fine. The expected value is therefore
$$\frac{m(n+1)}{2}.$$

**Problem (b)**

Here it seems better to proceed recursively.

Let $T(n,m)$ be the sum of the products of all possible sets of $m$ extractions.  Then the expected value of the product is $$\frac {T(n,m)}{n \text C m}.$$

The sum of the products for extractions not including the marble $n$ is $T(n-1,m)$.

For $m\ge 2$, the sum of the products for extractions including the marble $n$ is $nT(n-1,m-1)$.

Therefore, for $m\ge 2$  $$T(n,m)=T(n-1,m)+nT(n-1,m-1).$$

Comment: Ok but how do you  get the formula for the first case?...what I don't understand is how the expectation is the same for all the extractions...

Comment: By the 'first case' do you mean problem (a)? If so, then extract the marbles but don't look at them. This shows that the expected value of each extraction is the same as that of any other extraction.

Comment: Very interesting that recursion...Is there a way by using it to find a general "closed" solution?

Comment: I don't think so - certainly not one that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

The first formula that expands sum, is always true.

The second one is true **iff** they be independent, as yourself said.

But obviously they aren't! If it isn't clear to you suppose:
$$P(X_1=i=X_2)=0 \qquad \text{But} \qquad P(X_1=i)P(X_2=i)=\frac{1}{10}$$
In general case also you can use above to show they aren't independent.

If you want to use that formula and lookup for independent samples, you should take two, one by one, with replacing, so they can be same.